Print out items in array in Groovy
I have encountered a peculiar problem while I was working with arrays in Groovy
I have this array
def list = ["Basic","Advanced","Premium","Elite","Explore","Pioneer"]

I know that I can to print the item as follows, by manually inputting them
log.info("This is " + list[0] +", this is " + list[1] + "and this is " + list[2])

Output should be = This is Basic, this is Advanced and this is Premium

However, I want to make a different approach, I do not want to manually add all items. Is there a way to iterated the items and print them? Something similar to this
log.info ("This is " +  items in array iteration)

